# Histogram bin size

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a code like this and I am wondering why my bin size of the two plotted graphs is different?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
bins=15
pyplot.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,10)

#echte_Ladezeit
pyplot.hist(Y_test, bins, alpha=1, label='Y_test; orange Dateien', 
color='orange', weights = np.ones_like(Y_test)/float(len(Y_test)))
pyplot.hist(Y_train, bins, alpha=1, label='Y_train; grüne Dateien', 
color='green', weights = np.ones_like(Y_train)/float(len(Y_train)))
pyplot.title('Verteilung echte_Ladezeit')
pyplot.xlabel('echte_Ladezeit')
pyplot.ylabel('Häufigkeit [%]')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

actually the marked width of the orange and the green one should be the same right? Do I have any mistake in my code?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains `pyplot.hist(..., bins, ...)` where `bins = 15`. This means 15 bins equally spaced between max and min values. Max and min values are different for two datasets so you get different sets of 15 bins. If you want to get bins of equal width for every dataset then you have at least two options.

1. Normalize datasets - max and min values should be the same for both datasets.
2. Define bins as a sequence (for example, `list(range(0, 40000 + 1, 5000))`) as described [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).